# Select + optgroup : keeps highlight after losing focus on IE / Edge

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, optgroup

I'm facing a strange issue using Microsoft Edge on Windows 7 64 bits.

When using SELECT without OPTGROUP, the SELECT has no highlight after losing focus.
When using SELECT with OPTGROUP, the SELECT keeps highlight after losing focus.

Here is a simple example :

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <select name="test1">
            <optgroup label="Groupe 1">
                <option value="G11">Groupe 1 - Element 1</option>
                <option value="G12">Groupe 1 - Element 2</option>
                <option value="G13">Groupe 1 - Element 3</option>
                <option value="G14">Groupe 1 - Element 4</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Groupe 2">
                <option value="G21">Groupe 2 - Element 1</option>
                <option value="G22">Groupe 2 - Element 2</option>
                <option value="G23">Groupe 2 - Element 3</option>
                <option value="G24">Groupe 2 - Element 4</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>

        <select name="test2">
            <option value="S1">Element 1</option>
            <option value="S2">Element 2</option>
            <option value="S3">Element 3</option>
            <option value="S4">Element 4</option>
        </select>

        <input type="text" value="test3">
    </body>
</html>
```

It seems that there is an issue with the navigator, but I don't know how to avoid it. Maybe using CSS or a JS hack ?

Thanks for your help !